# Mapping List<String> from List<Object> using mapstruct

Tags: java, dto, mapstruct

Hi I am getting null for List action in DTO while setting it from the Child Source class using mapstruct. Could some help me in resolving this. Please find my code here

Entity Class:

```
public class Source {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<ChildSource> childSource;
    //getters and setters
}

public class ChildSource {
    String code;
    String action;
    //getters and setters   
}
```

DestinationDTO:

```
public class TargetDTO{
    int sNo;
    String mName;
    List<String> actions;
    //getters and setters  
}
```

MApper Class:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")    
public abstract class SampleMapper {
        @Mappings({ 
            @Mapping(target = "id", source = "sno"),
            @Mapping(target = "name", source = "mNAme")
        })
        public abstract TargetDTO toDto(Source source);

        @IterableMapping(elementTargetType = String.class)
        protected abstract List<String> mapStringtoList(List<ChildSource> childSource);

        protected String mapChildSourceToString(ChildSource child) {
            return child.getAction();
        }
    }
```

But my action list is setting as null in the target dto. Could anyone help me here please?

Comment: How does the generated code looks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219506/5456789

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")    
public abstract class SampleMapper {
        @Mappings({ 
            @Mapping(target = "id", source = "sno"),
            @Mapping(target = "name", source = "mNAme"),
            @Mapping(target = "actions", source = "childSource")
        })
        public abstract TargetDTO toDto(Source source);

        protected abstract List mapStringtoList(List childSource);

        protected String mapChildSourceToString(ChildSource child) {
            return child.getAction();
        }
    }
```

Comment: abstract method of `mapStringtoList` is not necessary  and you should add  `ChildSource childFromString(String child)` implementation

Answer (score 3):

Using a default method to map the ChildSource to a String.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")    
public abstract class SampleMapper {
    @Mappings({ 
        @Mapping(target = "id", source = "sno"),
        @Mapping(target = "name", source = "mNAme"),
        @Mapping(target = "actions", source = "childSource")
    })
    public abstract TargetDTO toDto(Source source);
    
    default String mapChildSourceToString(ChildSource child) {
        return child.getAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain how it answers the question.