# mapstruct - List<String> to List<Object>

Tags: java, spring, dto, mapstruct

I have a list of string in my DTO, i want to map it into a list of object, in the mapper i used the service to get the object by this string, but i have the below error

> Can't map property "java.util.List<java.lang.String> customers" to
>   "java.util.List<com.softilys.soyouz.domain.Customer> customers".
>
> Consider to declare/implement a mapping method:
>   "java.util.List<com.softilys.soyouz.domain.Customer>
>   map(java.util.List<java.lang.String> value)".

```
public class FirstDomain implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String  id;

    private String description;

    private List<Customer> customers;
}

public class FirstDomainDTO {

    private String id;

    private String description;

    private List<String> customers;
}

@Mapper(uses = { CustomerService.class })
public interface FirstDomainMapper extends EntityMapper<FirstDomainDTO, FirstDomain> {

    @Mapping(source = "customers", target = "customers")
    FirstDomainDTO toDto(FirstDomain firstDomain);

    @Mapping(source = "customers", target = "customers")
    FirstDomain toEntity(FirstDomainDTO firstDomainDTO);

    default String fromCustomer(Customer customer) {
        return customer == null ? null : customer.getCode();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try looking into qualifiedByName or qualifiedByClass  as a parameter in your @Mapping annotations to do your conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you are getting should be enough to help you understand what the problem is. In this case MapStruct doesn't know how to map from `List<String>` into `List<Customer>`. The other way around is OK since you have defined

```
default String fromCustomer(Customer customer) {
    return customer == null ? null : customer.getCode();
}
```

To fix this you need to defined the reverse as well.

```
@Mapper(uses = { CustomerService.class })
public interface FirstDomainMapper extends EntityMapper<FirstDomainDTO, FirstDomain> {

    @Mapping(source = "customers", target = "customers")
    FirstDomainDTO toDto(FirstDomain firstDomain);

    @Mapping(source = "customers", target = "customers")
    FirstDomain toEntity(FirstDomainDTO firstDomainDTO);

    default String fromCustomer(Customer customer) {
        return customer == null ? null : customer.getCode();
    }

    default Customer fromStringToCustomer(String customerId) {
        // Implement your custom mapping logic here
    }
}
```